# How to understand the xml is updated or not from c#(WPF) code

Tags: c#, xml

after updation of xml file,is there anything by which C# code will understand whether the code is been updated or not! Based on the success or failure response,i want to show output.

Comment: Please elaborate your question and show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: Only is you are using a schema and the schema changed.